# Check if record already exists within the database

Tags: c#, sql

I have a program that allows users to enter in movies and details about that movie and store them in a database. I have the database being displayed in my C# program and the user can select one of the rows and the information from that row will be put into the text box it corresponds to, for example the Title will go in the title text box and so on. what I want to do is stop the user hitting the submit button and putting the same record in the database.

Any help would be appreciated

Submit button:

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtTitle.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtRunTime.Text)) 
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Fill in all the required fields"); 
            }
            else 
            {

                if (lstStatus.SelectedIndex == 0) 
                {
                    Status = "Watched"; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    Status = "Not Watched"; 
                }

                if (lstType.SelectedIndex == 0) 
                {
                    Type = "Movie"; 
                }
                else 
                {
                    Type = "TV Show";
                } 

                con.Open(); 
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into dbo.Movies(Title, Genre, RunTime, Type, Status) values('"+txtTitle.Text+"','"+txtGenre.Text+"','"+txtRunTime.Text+"','"+Type+"','"+Status+"')", con); 
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
                MessageBox.Show("Data transferred into the database!"); 
                con.Close(); 

                txtTitle.Text = ""; 
                txtRunTime.Text = ""; /
            } 
        }
```

Code when selecting a row:

```
private void DataGridMovies_RowHeaderMouseClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if(DataGridMovies.CurrentRow.Index == DataGridMovies.Rows.Count - 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Empty row selected"); // Display a message to the user
            }
            else
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                txtTitle.Text = DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
                txtGenre.Text = DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                txtRunTime.Text = DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                if (DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value.ToString() == "Movie")
                {
                    lstType.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstType.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }// End of IF ELSE Statement
                if (DataGridMovies.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == "Watched")
                {
                    lstStatus.SelectedIndex = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    lstStatus.SelectedIndex = 1;
                }// End of IF ELSE Statement
            }//End of IF statement
```

Comment: Your approach to inserting data into the database permits sql injection attacks.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Shouldn't you have a view page that is separate from an edit/new page?

Comment: @BrootsWaymb I haven't tried anything because I am unsure how to go about it

Comment: @juharr I am pretty new to using databases with C# so this is the easiest way I found

Comment: If you research *data binding* a little you will find a much, much easier way.  The DB provider can and will do all the heavy lifting

Comment: How do you define a duplicate entry? For example, 2 or more movies can have the same title, so title can't be used to determine a duplicate.

Comment: @HoneyboyWilson I was gonna do it using the name of the movie and I get that 2 movies can be called the same but the chances of them also having the same runtime is very slim so I would do it by name and runtime or some other detail about the movie

Comment: You could select the count of rows where the title and runtime match your values. If the count is zero, then insert the row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use sql parameters or your sql database can be hacked.

You can read about that here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8
cmd.Parameters.AddWith(name, value)

Determine if the record exists. If it does not you are adding it with insert. If not you update the record instead.

Depending on the process power you have at your disposal you might also look into autocomplete. This can hide the fact they are just updating a record you already "found".
https://www.grapecity.com/blogs/dynamic-autocomplete-c1textbox

Meta tagging and algorithms on the back end sometimes take care of duplicate entries.

Comment: I should have said read about it here:  https://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/sql-injection/ and fix it with the link I already posted lol

Comment: I will change the way I insert my data to stop SQL injections, thanks

Comment: You should use a guid or int  for an identifier at the top level of each entry. Binding is a good idea especially if using a form. I would use the title, release year, and so on. You could really add some fancyness and look it up from this API https://www.themoviedb.org/documentation/api, that might be another lesson.